# Convert dynamic insert statement into parameterized statement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement, sql-injection

My application builds dynamic insert statements based on the incoming data.

For e.g., it dynamically builds an insert query like:

```
insert into employees (name, age) values ('Tim', 12)
```

(I use [sqlbuilder](http://openhms.sourceforge.net/sqlbuilder/) to generate queries like the above dynamically. I do not have any control over which columns/tables will make up the insert statement - it depends on the incoming data. For e.g., the next statement could be like: `insert into employees (building, salary) values ('Green tower', 9999)`)

I do not want to use the above statement as such since it is open for sql injection.

I need it to be converted into a PreparedStatement as follows:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertSQL);
preparedStatement.setString(1, "Tim");
preparedStatement.setInt(2, 99);
```

Is there any library that does it for me?

Comment: I get the feeling you might benefit from using [JPA](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Your tool does not rely on PreparedStatements, so there is no way of fixing that. What options you have:

- either pick a different tool to build your queries
- or make sure that your mechanism is protected from SQL Injection ([take a look at ESAPI](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet))